# Error in Quantum Espresso: cannot read atomic specie from: ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal}

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

Can you kindly help me understand the following type of error I get while calculating scf for bands?

```
The error is %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine  card_atomic_species (5010):
     cannot read atomic specie from: ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to MMSE! Can you show us the full input file? This error means that something is wrong with your input file. You can edit your question and add the full input file as `code` block.